# Can the inverse of a matrix with all entrances different from zero have zero entrances?

Tags: matrices

Assume X is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix with all entrances different from zero.

I was wondering: can its inverse have a zero in some entrance?

Comment: Yes, say $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 7 & 0 \\ 6 & 4 & 7 \\ 5 & 8 &10 \end{bmatrix}$, so $\det(A) = -223 \ne 0$, but $A^{-1}$ has no zero entries.

Comment: I was thinking of the other case around. A has no zero entrances but $A^{-1}$ has.

Comment: @jpugliese: the inverse of the inverse of $A$ is $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&1&1\\1&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$